# Silverlight application doesn't appears inside webform with masterpage

Tags: silverlight, webforms

my html test page were using

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/App.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

I added master page / website navigation and nothing is changed, it still being it

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/App.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

All scripts are the same but my silverlight application just doesn't load there. Why ? Can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two diagnostics I would use:-

- Use view source in the browser to confirm that the HTML is actually being composes as you expect.
- Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to observe the actual requests being made to the server.